# Creating a Button that changes the Background and Text Colors of different elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I'm trying to create a button that, when clicked, change the elements of a page to different colors combinations.

The idea is to have the colors changing in pairings when clicking the button. For example, when the **body is 'red'** and the **main titles are 'yellow'**, the **alternate titles and the border lines are 'red'** (same color of the body), and the **alternate background is 'yellow'** (same color of the main titles).

For some reason I can't make it work. The colors seem to be changing randomly instead of having an order, and I can't change the 'border-bottom' color.

```js
// Main titles color change

var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
var colorIndex = 0;
  
function changeText() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("textcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

// Body background color change
  
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeBackground() {
 var col = document.getElementsByClassName("bodycolor");
 if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
   colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

   
// Alternate titles and borders color change

var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var colorIndex = 0;
  
function changeTextAlt() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("alt-textcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

// Alternate background color change
  
var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeBackgroundAlt() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("alt-backgroundcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }
```

```css
body{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.66667;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    }
 

.textcolor{
    color: #000;
}

.bodycolor{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.alt-textcolor{
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.alt-backgroundcolor{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body class='bodycolor'>

<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground();changeText();changeTextAlt();changeBackgroundAlt();">Click me</button>

<p class='textcolor'>This is a title</p>

<div class='alt-backgroundcolor'>

<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 1</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 2</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 3</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 4</p>
</div>

<div class='bodycolor'>

<p class='textcolor'>This is another title</p>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead? 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cawuj20t/1/)

```
const colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
let colorIndex = 0;

function changeColor() {
    let col = document.getElementsByClassName("textcolor");
    let altCol = document.getElementsByClassName('alt-textcolor');

    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex+1];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

function changeAltColor() {
    let col = document.getElementById("bodycolor");
    let altCol = document.getElementById('alt-backgroundcolor');

    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }

    col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex+1];
    altCol.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;
    }
```

Considering you are only changing two colors at a time (alt color and main color), there's no need for 4 functions.

Also, if you have single elements such as `div` that have separate uses, then use `id` attribute for them instead of `class`, it's easier for writing code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it's not changing in order. There are times that all three colors are there instead of just two and the 'alternate titles' and the 'bottom border' are not changing. See here: https://prnt.sc/pgfyca